# Yii2 REST API update (put) when composite key

Tags: json, rest, yii2, put

I am trying to update my model via PUT http request in Yii2 framework.
Everything works fine when I have single Primary Key in my model.

Problems are when I have composite primary key in table.

How to update?

I submit JSON:

```
{"date_execution":"2017-08-26","order_id":"59", "company_id":13,"your_price":100,"car_id":"8","note":"lorem ipsum"}
```

my composite primary key include:
 - order_id
 - company_id

I tried following requests:

- PUT SERVER/offer/100 - where 100 is company_id
- PUT SERVER/offer/2000 - where 2000 is order_id

those 2 requests are returning problem:

```
{"name":"Not Found","message":"Object not found: 13","code":0,"status":404,"type":"yii\\web\\NotFoundHttpException"}
```

I also tried

- PUT SERVER/offer/2000/100 - where 2000 is order_id and 100 is company_id
- PUT SERVER/offer/100/2000

those 2 return controller/action not found exception

Also I added order_id and company_id to JSON,
but nothing works.

Controller Class:

```
use yii\rest\ActiveController;
class OfferController extends ActiveController
{
    // adjust the model class to match your model
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Offer';
    public function behaviors(){
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

        // remove authentication filter
        $auth = $behaviors['authenticator'];
        unset($behaviors['authenticator']);

        // add CORS filter
        $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
                'class' => CustomCors::className()
        ];

        // re-add authentication filter
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
                'class' => CompositeAuth::className(),
                'authMethods' => [
                        HttpBearerAuth::className(),
                ],
        ];
        // avoid authentication on CORS-pre-flight requests (HTTP OPTIONS method)
        $behaviors['authenticator']['except'] = ['options'];

        return $behaviors;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you have to create a custom action, because UpdateAction takes only $id parameter: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/rest/UpdateAction.php

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you use PUT SERVER/offer/2000,100

You can print primaryKey() of the model to know the order of the keys.

You can see it in the docs here
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-rest-action

> If composite primary key, the key values will be separated by comma.

Answer (score 1):

yii\rest\UpdateAction uses ActiveRecord::findModel() method to load data. There is an answer in those phpdoc:

> If the model has a composite primary key, the ID must be a string of
>   the primary key values separated by commas

So the right resource is (considering the first key field in the table structure is company_id)

```
PUT SERVER/offer/100,2000
```

Answer (score 0):

You firstly need to add primaryKey() in the model, to override the default primaryKey() of the ActiveRecord class. This function needs to return your composite primary key. 
What you need to do the model thus would be

```
primaryKey()
{
   return array('company_id', 'order_id');
}
```